# Closed stream (IO::Error) with HTTP::Client.get("https...")

Tags: crystal-lang

I am a bit confused with two codes.

```
    uri = URI.parse("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io")
    client = HTTP::Client.new(uri)
    client.get("/latest?base=EUR") do |response|
      p response.body_io.gets
    end
```

It works as expected, but

```
    response = HTTP::Client.get("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=EUR")
    p response
```

failed with

```
Closed stream (IO::Error)
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:128:5 in 'check_open'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/io/buffered.cr:99:5 in 'peek'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:632:37 in 'gets'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:591:5 in 'gets'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:814:5 in 'read_line:chomp'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/content.cr:205:7 in 'read_chunk_size'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/content.cr:187:26 in 'next_chunk'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/content.cr:120:7 in 'read'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/io.cr:554:29 in 'gets_to_end'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/client/response.cr:81:15 in 'consume_body_io'
         from lib/webmock/src/webmock/core_ext.cr:12:7 in 'exec_internal'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/client.cr:576:5 in 'exec'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/client.cr:698:5 in 'exec'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/client.cr:730:7 in 'exec'
         from /usr/share/crystal/src/http/client.cr:402:3 in ‚get
```

I use Crystal 0.33. Any idea what could fix second code?

Comment: Uhhhh to fix it perhaps remove the influence of `lib/webmock/src/webmock/core_ext.cr`?

Comment: Yep, @OlehPrypin you right, without webmock all works as expected. Drop an issue there https://github.com/manastech/webmock.cr/issues/41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the log I see `lib/webmock/src/webmock/core_ext.cr` (which normally shouldn't be there), seems like its influence is causing the problem, and the code in isolation would just work.